# How to find the first three strings, which start with a lower-case `a` in a sorted order

Tags: java, foreach, java-stream

Java 8 Stream API /

How to find the first three strings, which start with a lower-case `a` in a sorted order. How to Print out the result with `System.out.println()`.

```
List<String> myList =

   Arrays.asList("A1", "a2", "b1", "c2", "A2", "a3", "c2", "A3", "c2", "a1", "a4", "a6");

       myList.stream().filter(s -> s.startsWith("a"))

             .map(String::toLowerCase)

             .sorted()

             .forEach(s ->System.out.println("Filtered value: " + s));
```

How can print only the first three strings, which start with a lower-case `a` in a sorted order?

### please help

& In This Case: I don´t understand this Task with nested:
How can print only the first three strings, which start with a lower-case a in a sorted order?

public class Task {

```
public static void main(String[] args){

final List<String> myList1 =
    Arrays.asList("c1", "b2", "G3", "g4", "b1",
                  "b3", "G5", "g3", "b5", "e2", "b8", "b2",
                  "g8", "i9", "b10", "j6", "s2", "g2", "B9",
                  "B1", "g7", "b8", "N7", "e9");
final List<String> myList2 =
    Arrays.asList("c1", "b2", "G3", "g4", "b1",
                  "b3", "G5", "g3", "b5", "e2", "b8", "b2",
                  "g8", "i9", "b10", "j6", "s2", "g2", "B9",
                  "B1", "g7", "b8", "N7", "e9");

List<List<String>> nestedList = new ArrayList<>();
nestedList.add(myList1);
nestedList.add(myList2);}}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work - need to tell the List what type of Object you are working with

```
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("A1", "a2", "b1", "c2", "A2", 
                                   "a3", "c2", "A3", "c2", "a1", "a4", "a6");

myList.stream().filter(s -> s.startsWith("a")).sorted().limit(3)
forEach(s ->System.out.println("Filtered value: " + s));
```

Also as you only want lowercase `a` there is no need to convert to lowercase.

Comment: Tthanks for  answer. BUT: How can print only the first three strings, which start with a lower-case a?

Comment: @Spring Did this work, if so please upvote and accept an answer

Comment: Great. It sorts and gives the first three strings .. Thanks – Scary Wombat 
--------------------
Filtered value: a1
Filtered value: a2
Filtered value: a3

Comment: It just missed the point before forEach. Thanks – Scary Wombat 
myList.stream().filter(s -> s.startsWith("a")).sorted().limit(3)
     .forEach(s ->System.out.println("Filtered value: " + s));

Comment: if the Arrays.asList are like that: 
Arrays.asList("A1", "a2", "b1", "a11", "a10", "c2", "A2", "a3", "c2", "A3", "c2", "a1", "a4", "a6"); 
Then the output is as follows: 
a1
a10
a11
And that´s wrong

Comment: *a1 a10 a11* - try sorting this in excel and you will that maybe it is just your understanding that is wrong.  if would the first bit to be an alpha sort and the second part to be a numeric sort, then that is a completely different question to what you asked.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash - why ambush my answer with your comment?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I would have thought that it would have been better to comment below the main question for more visibility.  I am glad that you have submitted an answer which I feel is different to my answer which deals with the OP's original question.  **However** looking at `myList1` etc there does not even seem to be any `a?` elements, so at the end of the day, I think nobody can be sure what this ghost wants

Answer (score 1):

You could add `.limit(3)` to your stream after sorting.
The list needs to be typed `List<String>` to use the String methods, and you don't need the `toLowerCase` unless you want the results transformed to lower case.

```java
List<String> myList = List.of(
    "A1", "a2", "b1", "c2", "A2", "a3", "c2", "A3", "c2", "a1", "a4", "a6");
myList.stream().filter(s -> s.charAt(0) == 'a').sorted().limit(3)
    .forEach(s -> System.out.println("Filtered value: " + s));
```

**Update:** For numeric ordering from index 1 of each String:

```java
Comparator<String> comparator = Comparator.comparing(
    s -> Integer.parseInt(s.substring(1)));
myList.stream().filter(s -> s.charAt(0) == 'a').sorted(comparator).limit(3)
    .forEach(s -> System.out.println("Filtered value: " + s));
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. if the Arrays.asList are like that: Arrays.asList("A1", "a2", "b1", "a11", "a10", "c2", "A2", "a3", "c2", "A3", "c2", "a1", "a4", "a6"); Then the output is as follows: a1 a10 a11 And that´s wrong

Comment: What order would you expect in this case?

Comment: a1, a2, a3 and not a1, a10, a11 because that´s wrong

Comment: So you don't want alphanumeric ordering, you want to order by the numeric value from index 1 of the string. Is that right?

Comment: Jes,  order by the numeric value from index 1 of the string.

Comment: Added new comparator in answer above

Comment: Thanks. Great. It sorts and gives the first three strings.

Comment: @ -boot-and-bonnet, How to solve the same question with nested? See pl. my new comment. Thanks

Comment: Start the stream with `nestedList.stream().flatMap(List::stream)` which will flatten lists into a single stream

Comment: Comparator<String> comparator = Comparator.comparing(
             s -> Integer.parseInt(s.substring(1)));
                nestedList.stream().flatMap(List::stream)(s -> s.charAt(0) == 'a').sorted(comparator).limit(3)
             .forEach(s -> System.out.println("Filtered value: " + s));

Answer (score 0):

Please find below code for the same :

```
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("A1", "a2", "b1", "c2", "A2", "a3", "c2", "A3", "c2", "a1", "a4", "a6");
            myList.stream().filter(x-> x.startsWith("a")).sorted().limit(3).forEach(System.out :: println);
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for your answer. Rather than just posting a block of code, can you give a short explanation to what the issue is you solved and how you solved it? This will help people who find this question in the future to better understand the issue and how to deal with it.

Comment: Here I have filtered the element which starts with "a" using stream filter and used stream sorted method to sort the elements in the natural order.
sorted() method take comparator as input, however, if we need to sort in other than the natural order (say descending order) we need to give comparator as imput ((x,y)-> y.compareTo(x))
Then I have used the steam limit() method and taken the top 3 elements by giving 3 as input.
Then I have used stream forEach() method which is used to do terminal operation as stream is lazily executed and print the elements

Comment: I hope the above explanation is helpful